# using IN condtion in SQL CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-3.5

How we can we pass list of values as parameters in SQLCE?

using the below code works (when directly passing list of values in query)

```
    SqlCeCommand cmd = string.Format("Select VMID from Booking where (VMID in ({0})", 
                       selectedVMs );
    SqlCeManager.OpenSqlConnection();//my custom code to open sql connection
    sqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmd, SqlCeManager.sqlConn);
```

But the below code does not work ( when passing the list of values using the parameters).

```
    SqlCeCommand cmd = "Select VMID from Booking where (VMID in (@VMIDs))";
    SqlCeManager.OpenSqlConnection();//my custom code to open sql connection     
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VMIDs", string.Join(",", selectedVMs));
    sqlCmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmd, SqlCeManager.sqlConn);
```

The error i get is **"@IDs : 8,7 - Input string was not in a correct format."**

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Your missing that there's a logical difference between providing two parameters to `IN()`, separated by commas, versus providing a *single* parameter to `IN()` that happens to be a string that contains a comma.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you are right and it makes sense. Thanks for your quick post.

Comment: Looking for a cleaner way to pass a list of values using parameters option.

Comment: For full-blown SQL Server, I'd recommend table-values parameters. I'm not sure if CE supports those (and if so, on which versions)